# Display Stopwatch to screen?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, stopwatch

I have been trying to make a stopwatch now for the past few days. I think I just need to figure out how to actually get it to display to the screen and update every second, milli seconds etc. Any code I have put in wont display the timer to the screen and actually show what's happening. I will post the code below and the errors I'm getting. Any help input would be amazing. Thanks.

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    private const string Format = "{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}";

    DispatcherTimer dTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    string currentTime = string.Empty;


    public MainPage()
    { 

        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        stopWatch.Stop();
        // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
        TimeSpan tSpan = stopWatch.Elapsed;

        // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
        string ClockTextBlock = String.Format(Format,
            tSpan.Hours, tSpan.Minutes, tSpan.Seconds,
            tSpan.Milliseconds / 10);
        Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + ClockTextBlock);
        InitializeComponent();

        InitializeComponent();

        dTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dt_Tick);
        dTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);

        void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (stopWatch.IsRunning)
            {
                TimeSpan t = stopWatch.Elapsed;
                currentTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}",
                    tSpan.Hours, tSpan.Minutes, tSpan.Seconds);
                ClockTextBlock.ToString (currentTime);
            }
        }


    }

    public String Display(Object sender, String ClockTextBlock)
    {

        return ClockTextBlock + String.Format(Format);
    }
    public void StartButton_Click(Object sender, Stopwatch stopwatch)
    {
        dTimer.Start();
    }

    public void StopButton_Click(Object sender, Stopwatch stopwatch)
    {
        dTimer.Stop();
    }
    public void ResetButton_Click(Object sender, Stopwatch stopwatch)
    {
        stopwatch.Reset();
    }




}
```

}

Errors:

> cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider'code
>   DispatcherTimer.Tick' is not supported by the language; try directly
>   calling accessor methods
>   'DispatcherTimer.add_Tick(EventHandler)' or
>   'DispatcherTimer.remove_Tick(EventRegistrationToken)'

Comment: What's wrong with it, you get any errors? If so, edit your question and list them

Comment: Your Stopwatch remains stopped after you call `stopwatch.Stop();`

Comment: You have two variables `stopWatch`. You probably only want one.

Comment: Just posted the errors.

Comment: Yeah you are right Andrew, Sorry it's been a long one.

Comment: Why does it remain stopped when the stop method is called Nick?

Comment: To get a TimeSpan of 10 seconds for testing, you do not have to wait that long, but can use `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach. It can be done easily with an [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) method. Check this:

```
async void UpdateLoop()
{
    while (true) //your condition when it should stop
    {
        label.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("T");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Of course you don't need to display actual time, but you can keep your time in a variable.
And you can call the `UpdateLoop()` method from any method/constructor. This peace of code is from [the official Xamarin.Forms book](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/) (page 721). I recommended to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar which might help you. Basically I wanted to show the length of time some hardware had been booted for. I had a label in the View which was bound to a property. I then created a dispatcher which called a method every 50 ms which updated the property. In the example below it starts when the constructor for the View-Model is called.

XAML

```
<Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding TimePortModuleIsUp}" />
```

View-Model

```
 private string timePortModuleIsUp;

 /// <summary>
 /// Gets / Sets how long the port module has been booted for.
 /// </summary>
 public string TimePortModuleIsUp
 {
  get
  {
       return timePortModuleIsUp;
  }
  Set
  {
       timePortModuleIsUp = value;
       OnPropertyChanged("TimePortModuleIsUp");
  }
 }
```

Create a DispatcherTimer object.

```
private DispatcherTimer t;
```

Constructor in View-Model

This creates a dispatcher object that calls t_tick every 50ms and starts it off.

```
// Create a dispatcher that calls t_tick every 50 ms.
t = new DispatcherTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 50), DispatcherPriority.Background, t_Tick, Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher);

// Start the timer.
t.IsEnabled = true;
```

and finally the method that is called every 50 ms that updates the property the label is bound to.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Method that updates a property representing how long the port module has been booted for.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.TimePortModuleIsUp = new DateTime((DateTime.Now - this.ModuleBootTime).Ticks).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    }
```